# JSF ui:repeat in ui:repeat with dynamically assigned var-value

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, repeat, composite-component, uirepeat

We created a JSF table component for our projects which uses `<ui:repeat>` to create the table. A new requirement to add a table inside a table (the second table resides in a row and is collapsable) has gotten us into trouble as the `<ui:repeat var="row" ...>` is set statically inside the table componenten and the inner table uses the row variable of the outer table when iterating through the list. Now what i want to create is something like this:

```
<div>
   <myfw:mytable dataModel="#{bean.user}" varName="user" ...>
      <myfw:mycolumn value="#{user.name}"/>
      <myfw:myexpendablecolumn>
         <myfw:mytable dataModel="#{bean.acl}" varName="acl" ...>
            <myfw:mycolumn value="#{acl.name}"/>    
         </myfw:mytable>
      </myfw:myexpendablecolumn>
   </myfw:mytable>
</div>
```

In the table component the var attribute should be set ...

```
<composite:interface>
...
    <composite:attribute name="varName" required="false"
        type="java.lang.String" default="row" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
...

        <ui:repeat var="#{varName}" value="#{cc.attrs.dataModel.wrappedData}"
            varStatus="loop">
            <div class="floating_table_row">
                              <composite:insertChildren />  
            </div>
        </ui:repeat>
</composite:implementation>
```

... but sadly, this does not work. I've tried it with `<c:forEach>` but the result is the same, the values of the columns are empty and no data is shown. Is there a way to dynamically set the var attribut of the `<ui:repeat>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I stumbled over this page https://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-372 where the UIRepeat class, specifically the `getVar` method is modified to access the ValueExpression so instead of

```
public String getVar() {
    return this.var;
}
```

... the method looks like this:

```
public String getVar() {
    if (this.var != null) {
        return this.var;
    }
    ValueExpression ve = this.getValueExpression("var");
    if (ve != null) {
        return (String) ve.getValue(getFacesContext().getELContext());
    }
    return null;
}
```

There are further modifications in the attached file from https://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-372. Sadly, the `UIRepeat`class cannot be simply extended because of the usage of the `var` attribute in private methods so I now have a `<myfw:repeat>` which utilises the patched `UIRepeat` class from the page.