# JSF1064 when using tags defined in the taglib.xml

Tags: jsf, warnings, custom-component, taglib

I've created my own custom `myfw:repeat` tag for our project as described in [JSF ui:repeat in ui:repeat with dynamically assigned var-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337016/jsf-uirepeat-in-uirepeat-with-dynamically-assigned-var-value) and defined it in the `myfw.taglib.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" id="myfw">

    <namespace>http://company.at/myfw</namespace>
    <composite-library-name>myfw</composite-library-name>

<!-- Other tags -->

    <tag>
        <tag-name>repeat</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>at.company.myfw.jsf.component.repeat.UIRepeatForFloatingTable</component-type>
        </component>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

The tag used in the page is working fine but every time the page is viewed the warning message:

```
13:03:30,577 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, repeat.xhtml, from library, myfw.
```

shows up in the logs. This is not just the case with the repeat tag, it also happens to every tag defined in the taglib like `ui:compositions`. So the log is currently spammed by these messages but the page/tags work properly.  A current workaround is to change the log-level, but it is not the desired solution. Using EAP 6.2.0.GA with Mojarra 2.1.19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Mojarra. It's during `Development` stage too eagerly logging JSF1064 for tagfiles which couldn't be found in `<composite-library-name>`, while it should still continue to work through `<tag>` entries registered directly in taglib itself.

This is not your fault. Those warnings aren't logged in `Production` stage. I reported this issue as [JAVASERVERFACES-3696](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3696) (**update**: this was fixed only a few hours later and will be available as per Mojarra 2.3.0-M02).

Comment: Thank you for your response and your solution. Your right, the logs only appear on my local JBoss dev instance. Currently I'm bound to Mojarra 2.1 due to company policy but will update as soon as it's possible.